# What piece of waltz is quoted by Victor Wooten in this SMV concert?

Tags: identify-this-song

Here is the link to the [video](https://youtu.be/43gIIyJWQII?t=47s) (at 47s), from the SMV (Staley Clarke, Marcus Miller, Victor Wooten) concert at the Vitoria Gasteiz Jazz Festival (in 2009).

Comment: Write him yourself and ask him. His email address is at his website, here: http://victorwooten.com/crew.html

Comment: @Wheat Williams, you're joking, right?

Comment: No, I am not joking. I know Victor Wooten personally. He's a nice guy and always interested in helping out musicians. He is very busy, but if he is available, he will reply to your email.

Comment: sounds a bit like a simple piece from the baroque or classical era that a person might have played in the early stages of learning piano. Any music teachers on here ?

Answer (score -1):

Jesu, Joy of Man's Desiring, by Bach. The main phrasing sounds a little backwards to me, like it's descending chords instead of ascending, but the finish gives it away. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwWL8Y-qsJg) it is on Youtube, you may compare yourself.

Comment: I disagree.  I suppose this Victor Wooten bit could be based on "Jesu, Joy of Man's Desiring" (JJOMD), with certain parts being flipped and so forth, or inspired by it, or something like that.  But I don't hear noticeably hear JJMOD when I watch that Wooten video.

Comment: Whereas I just listened to both again and I think it could hardly be clearer. Maybe it's because I've played Jesu in the orchestra on second violin, so I've heard it more more, or heard it without the rest of the orchestra?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to some other movement of _Herz und Mund und Tat und Leben_ (BWV 147) besides the tenth movement, which is normally referred to as "Jesu, Joy of Man's Desiring"?  It's doubtful, but I'm still wondering, since that might explain the different way that you and I are hearing this.  I hear Wooten's melody as (scale degrees) "5 3 1 4 2 low7 1 2 3 2 low7 low5" (repeat), whereas I hear Jesu's quintessential melody as "(1 2) 3 5 4 4 6 5 5 high1 7 h1 5 3 1 2 3" (etc.).  Maybe you're thinking of a different passage or a different voice part (2nd violin)?

Comment: Is the finish you're referring to something like (scale degrees) "6 high1 7 high1"?  That's hardly uncommon enough to match these two melodies together.

Comment: No, I'm definitely referring to Jesu. It's the opening phrase of the youtube I linked. I concede that Wooten has changed its character some, but to me it sounds still clearly recognizable.

Comment: Maybe I'll email Wooten, as Wheat Williams suggested above, to see if I'm just crazy on this one.

Comment: (oops, sorry, chat didn't work the way expected).  E-mailing Wooten would be awesome.  Hadn't seen that comment from @Wheat Williams.

Comment: Ok, email sent. I will post back if there is any reply.

Comment: I disagree, too. True, both pieces are 3 in a bar. But Wooten's theme has one chord-change per bar, straight 4-bar phrases, and a simple I - V alternation which lasts through the first 12 bars.  "Jesu, Joy of Man's Desiring" is in a much slower 3, with chord-changes on every beat of a bar, or on beats 1 and 3. I-V alternation is not so pervasive. If you speed Jesu up so each bar is like one of Wooten's bars, that means chords change too often. If you slow Jesu down so each beat is like one of Wooten's bars, that means 3-bar phrases, not 4.